# Handle a hierarchical sparse matrix in fortran

Tags: fortran, sparse-matrix, blas, intel-mkl

**Introduction**

I am developing a code in Fortran solving an MHD problem with preconditioning of a linear operator. The sparse matrix to be inverted can be considered as a matrix of the following hierarchical structure. The original matrix (say, A_1) is a band matrix of blocks. Each block of A_1 is a sparse matrix (say, A_2) of the same structure (i.e. a block banded matrix). Each block of A_2 is again a block banded matrix of the same sparsity structure, A_3. Each block of A_3 is, finally, a dense matrix 5 by 5, A_4. I find this hierarchical representation is very convenient to initialize elements of the matrix.

**Question**

I wonder if there exists a library (in Fortran) permitting to handle such a structure and convert it in one of the standard sparse matrix formats (CSR, CSC, BSR,...), since Sparse BLAS or MKL Pardiso will be used to invert it. Let me stress that my intention is to use the hierarchical structure only to initialize elements of the matrix. Of course, the hierarchical structure can be disregarded and the matrix could be hard-coded in the CSR format, but I find this is too time consuming to implement and test.

**Comments**

1. I don't expect a linear solver to use the hierarchical structure, although in S. Pissanetsky " Sparse matrix technology", 1984, Academmic Press, page 27 (available online [here](http://enpub.fulton.asu.edu/powerzone/SparseVisual/chapter%201/Chapter%201/1-11.html)) such storage schemes are mentioned, namely, the "hypermatrix" and "supersparse" storage schemes, and were used in Gauss elimination. I have not found available implementations of these schemes yet.
2. Block compressed sparse row (BSR) format (supported by MKL) can be used to handle two levels of the matrix, A_3(sparse) + A_4(dense), not more.

Comment: You should have a look on [sparskit](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~saad/software/SPARSKIT/) and [SLEPC/PETSC](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/), they may be useful for your purpose.